# DNS with VPN (local vs. remote DNS)

Tags: vpn, dns

My computer is connected to the work domain, where it gets the local dns-servers along with the dhcp-settings.

For a certain customer, i'm connecting to their network using VPN (Open VPN / TAP-Device) which ofc. sets up a second ip along with their DNS Servers.

The problem i'm facing, is that Windows 10 seems to be unable to decide which DNS-Server to query: let's say the domains are `ad.customer.com` and `ad.mysite.com`.

When the connection is established, windows 10 by default uses the dns-server of the remote-site, i.e. `dns1.ad.customer.com`. Local DNS resolution now fails, which makes local file-shares, printers, etc. pp. inaccessible.

The problem is obviously, that the domain-names are sub-domains of a valid tld:

- The PC starts to ask the remote-dns-server for `mysite.com` - which could be resolved online.
- But then ofc, the online-domain-controller responsibe for `mysite.com` does not have any information for `ad.mysite.com`, because this is only handled by the local dns-server(s)
- tracerouting any internal name shows, that windows clearly tries to resolve it *this* way...

If I modify the metrics of the network connections (local vs TAP) then it behaves the other way round: I'm able to access local resources even if VPN is established, but obviously i'm not able to resolve hostnames on the `ad.customer.com`-domain, because now the same thing vice-versa happens:

- Windows is asking my local DNS for `customer.com`
- the request is forwarded to the DNS Server responsible for `cusotmer.com` - which in turn is the "online-version" and not aware of the internal `ad`-subdomain.

Is there a way to tell Windows which Connection / DNS-Server should be used for a certain FQDN?

Or could I setup my `dc1.ad.mysite.com` to respond in a way, that the client knows he needs to query `dc1.ad.customer.com` (ip) instead?

(Setting up a dns-forwarder ofc. will not work, because the internal-dns servers aren't connected, since the VPN-Connection originates from my machine)

So to say, I would need DNS-Redirection, not DNS-Forwarding.

Local One is 2012 R2, if that has an impact on the options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out: Both `online-dns` servers (`customer.com` and `mysite.com`) had wildcard records setup, i.e. a `A-record` like `*.mysite.com`

Therefore, when the `ad.customer.com` internal DNS was queried for a fqdn on `ad.mysite.com`, it was forwarded to OUR online-dns, the online-DNS responsible for `mysite.com` answered with the primary IP due to it's wildcard-A-record:

[image]

I cannot change the Domain-Records for the customer, but i can change ours. So, I configured the metrics in order that the `remote` connection is used first, but for our tld, I disabled the wildcard-record, leaving only `valid` hostnames to be answered.

So, if a VPN-Connection is established now, Windows will start to query the customers local dns, even for internal hostnames, but then no longer receives a wrong answer (due to forwarding to the online-dns) but nothing.

NOW Windows seems to query the dns servers of the secondary connection (local one, higher metric), which then works and leads to the correct result:

[image]

---

Knowing the cause, another - maybe better - solution was easy to find: 
While Solution 1 would always query the customers local DNS first, this one works with querying our local dns first:

First, ofc. Metrics of the two connections have been changed, so that the local connection is used first.

Inside our local DNS-Server I setup a Primary-Zone, matching the customers domain: `customer.com` - and left it empty.

Now, our local DNS will answer with `not found` rather than forwarding the query to the customers wildcard-using-online-dns-server. (Which cannot resolve their internal names)

My PC will now use the second (remote) connection, where the query for internal names can be resolved.

Drawback: Without an established VPN-Connection, I can no longer access the customers website, because our local dns is no longer forwarding these queries.

If I would need that as well, I could setup A-records in the "Fake-primary-Zone" ofc.

Answer (score 0):

VPN servers are the only one that can really help to have access to ones data from any where in the world, and it is encrypted therefore safe.

I have set-up my own VPN Server using Raspberry Pi 3 in the UK and it is working like a charm since it has been set-up, no problem at all, the set-up is TCP/IP and I am planing to set another one up with UDP.

Siamak